# NET STOP not stopping SQL Server services

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am creating a batch program which will stop the services of SQL Server and copy `.mdf` and `.ldf` files to a specified location.

This is my batch file:

```
 net stop mssqlserver

 xcopy /s "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf"  "D:\backup"

 xcopy /s "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf"  "D:\backup"

 net start mssqlserver
```

It is stopping SQL Server **Agent**, but not SQL Server itself, so it cannot copy the files.

Why is it not stopping the SQL Server service?

What do I need to do to stop the SQL Server service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any output from the batch?

Comment: Related question is : [Stop SQL Server from running until needed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17284228/4519059) ;).

Comment: Do you get any (error) message(s) when running this `NET STOP` command separately, from the `cmd.exe` command line?

Comment: Are you sure your `SQL Server` service `instance name` is `mssqlserver`? It may have been installed using `named instance`. Check the `InstalledInstances` value under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server` registry key, or run `sc query mssqlserver` to test if it is the real friendly name of the service.

Comment: Read more here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dugi/2010/06/23/stop-n-start-sql-services-via-command-prompt/

Comment: Thanks  all for reply .  I found solution from Microsoft Support site and did following steps :-
1. Pause MS SQL Server with net pause mssqlserver
2. Stop Sqlserver Agent  with net stop sqlserveragent
3. Stop MS SQL Server with net Stop  mssqlserver

recommend always use this approach for properly stopping services of SQL Server ..